# Change image of sprite andengine

Tags: android, andengine

Hi i am using Andengine to make an Game application

in that i want to change the background image of an sprite when i click on that sprite. can any body help me how to do that.

```java
this.mFaceTextureRegionBackOn = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(this.mTextureBackOn);
this.mFaceTextureRegionBackOff = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(this.mTextureBackOff);

final ButtonSprite back = new ButtonSprite(centerXBack, centerYBack, this.mFaceTextureRegionBackOn, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
scene.attachChild(back);
back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ButtonSprite arg0, float arg1, float arg2) {
        MainActivity.this.mFaceTextureRegionBackOn = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(MainActivity.this.mTextureBackOff);
    }
});
```

there is a sprite button when i click on that button it's texture region i am changing but it could not help me to change image of that sprite

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a similar usage in AndEngineExamples, see https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/UpdateTextureExample.java

Comment: But it requires reading from disk each time, which can be slower.

Comment: @Mustafa then you should consider use normal TiledSprite, and load your tiled texture region in the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you just create two sprites and switch their visibilities? I switch sound on\off buttons in this way:

```
soundOnBtn = new Sprite(TILE_SIZE/2, 0, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, gameResources.getSoundOnTR())
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY)
        {
            soundOn = !soundOn;
            soundOnBtn.setVisible(soundOn);
            soundOffBtn.setVisible(!soundOn);
            return true;
        }
    };
    mainScene.registerTouchArea(soundOnBtn);
    soundOffBtn = new Sprite(TILE_SIZE/2, 0, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, gameResources.getSoundOffTR());
    soundOffBtn.setVisible(false);
    bottomPanelLayer.attachChild(soundOnBtn);       
    bottomPanelLayer.attachChild(soundOffBtn);
```